# \DeclarePairedDelimiter with \left & \right no longer works

Tags: mathtools

The following MWE worked in December 2015 based on the archived PDF. But, it does not work today. Any idea?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\eceil}{\left\lceil}{\right\rceil}

\begin{document}
$\eceil{\cdot}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: @ChristianHupfer mathtools does not use expl3, it uses a self defined syntax similar to expl3, but not expl3

Comment: @daleif: Hm, I was pretty sure that `mathtools` is defined with `expl3`. Ok, thanks

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Morten wrote mathtools at a time when expl3 was not particularly stable. Made a subset of the syntax and used it as a kind of test case. The next version will clean it up a bit, so there are no macro overlap

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should not use `left` and `right` in the `DeclarePairedDelimiter` definition. Those are automatically used when you use the command defined there.

You would use the starred version for autoscaling, i.e. `\left` and `\right` like

So

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\eceil}{\lceil}{\rceil}

\begin{document}
$\eceil{\cdot}$\\[3ex]

$\eceil*{\frac{\frac{a}{c}}{\frac{b}{d}}}$
\end{document}
```

Should work fine and produce

[image]

Comment: You're pace is increasing ;-) You were quicker...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I've seen too many `DeclarePairedDelimiter` and TeXBook Appendix G to be still so slow on these questions

Comment: I follow your suggestion in removing \left and \right. But, it does not work for $\eceil{\frac{\frac{a}{c}}{\frac{b}{d}}}$. For this, the use of \left and \right vertically scaled the \lceil and \rceil in the archived PDF from 2015.

Comment: @TadeusPrastowo you want to use the starred version, sorry, I did not write that. Corrected now