# Missing { inserted: \DeclarePairedDelimiterX

Tags: errors, mathtools, definition

The following code

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\innerp[2]{\left(}{\right)}{#1 \delimsize\vert \mathopen{}#2}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\dualp}[2]{\langle}{\rangle}{#1\, , \mathopen{}#2}
\begin{document}
%
\[
    \innerp{a}{b}
\]
%
%
\[
    \dualp{a}{b}
\]
%
\end{document}
```

Gives the following error code:

```
./mwe.tex:8: Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \left 
l.8     \innerp{a}{b}
```

I have just replaced the \langle by \left( and the \rangle by \right) . So I am wondering what is wrong.

Comment: `\left` and `\right` are wrong. Just use `(` and `)`.

Comment: As campa mentions `\left/right` has no relevancy here as they are applied automatically via `\innerp*`. Tip if you use `\delimsize\lvert` instead, then you don't need the `\mathopen`.

Comment: @daleif Do you think this might be a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/368641/82917? It's not quite literal, but similar (BTW has this really ever worked?)

Comment: @campa I think it is a duplicate of that. If `{\left(}` ... has ever worked it would have been a very long time ago. I do not recall it ever being a supported feature.